# flask, sqlalchemy, таблица рекордов

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть учебный проект, сделано все, кроме таблицы рекордов. В проекте имеются 4 игры, в 2-х из них есть счет (flappybird, snake). Вопрос заключается в следующем: как вытащить из игры счет и добавить в базу данных ( (flaskblog/models.py) см User поля     score_snake = db.Column(db.Integer)
score_bird = db.Column(db.Integer) )
Ссылочка на проект https://github.com/rmrf51/stankingames 
Если можно, то объясните на примере flappybird ( flaskblog/templates/games/flappyBird/ )

Убил часа 4, ничего не нашел и не нагуглил, заранее спасибо!

Comment: какой счет? с какой игры?

Comment: flaskblog/templates/games/flappyBird/ (https://github.com/rmrf51/stankingames/tree/master/flaskblog/templates/games/flappyBird)
там все игры на js (canvas) написаны и сделаны просто как отдельные страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил с помощью ajax, кому интересно https://github.com/rmrf51/stankingames/tree/newBranchSite